# Initialize tensor from another tensor's value

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow I have two convolutional netural networks A and B that are slightly different. Both networks have the same number of filters and layers. I want to do some pre-training in A and then use the learned weights to initalise those in B. I haven't managed to make this work. I think that the problem is that the initializer erases the operation of copying the values of each tensor in A to that in B.

This is what I've done:

I train A and save the model once I reach 90% acc (I'm using MNIST for this stest so just 50 iter is engouh). I save the model like this:

```
save_path = tf.train.Saver().save(sess, logdir + "modelA.ckpt")
print("Model A saved in file: %s" % save_path)
sess.close()
```

Then, I load model A as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("path/to/modelA.ckpt.meta")
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("path/to/logs"))
```

Finally, I try to initalise the weights in net B with it's corresponding weight in A by doing:

```
with tf.name_scope("NetB"):
    def init_weight(shape, name, stddev=0.1):
        initial = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=stddev, name=name))
        return initial.assign(graph.get_tensor_by_name("nameOfTensorInNetA"))
```

I follow the same procedure to initalise the bias elements.

Any ideas why this won't work and how to do it?

Comment: You say it doesn't work, but what is it doing?  Are you getting an error?  Also, what are you doing with the result of the `init_weight` function?  `assign` returns an op which needs to be run to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours struggling with this I came with a solution (probably not the nicest one). This is what I've done:

1. Load the model (as described in my question) and store the value of each of the trainable variables (weights and biases) that are going to be initialised. For this purpose, I construct a dictionary where the key is the name of a tensor in model A and the value is the value of that tensor:

   ```
   initDict = {}
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       data_path = "path/to/modelA_dir/"
       saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(data_path+"modelA.ckpt.meta")
       saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(data_path))
       for var in tf.trainable_variables():
           initDict[var.name] = sess.run(var)
   tf.reset_default_graph() # resets the graph
   ```
2. I wrote a short script to previsualise the network structure in a table:

   ```
   def showArchAsTable():
       totalSize = 0
       t = PrettyTable(['VarName', 'Shape', 'Size(MB)'])
       for var in tf.trainable_variables():
            size = (np.product(list(map(int, var.shape))) * var.dtype.size)/(1024.0 ** 2) # get variable size in MegaBytes
            t.add_row([var.name, var.shape, size])
            totalSize += size

       print(t) # print table
       print("Total size:", totalSize, "MB")
   ```

   This outputs the following. Network A structure:

   ```
   +------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
   |              VarName               |      Shape      |      Size(MB)     |
   +------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
   |  NetA/ConvL_1/weights/weights_1:0  |  (7, 7, 1, 32)  |  0.0059814453125  |
   |   NetA/ConvL_1/biases/biases_1:0   |      (32,)      |  0.0001220703125  |
   |  NetA/ConvL_2/weights/weights_1:0  |  (5, 5, 32, 64) |     0.1953125     |
   |   NetA/ConvL_2/biases/biases_1:0   |      (64,)      |   0.000244140625  |
   |  NetA/ConvL_3/weights/weights_1:0  | (3, 3, 64, 128) |      0.28125      |
   |   NetA/ConvL_3/biases/biases_1:0   |      (128,)     |   0.00048828125   |
   | NetA/FullyConL/weights/weights_1:0 |    (6272, 10)   |    0.2392578125   |
   |  NetA/FullyConL/biases/biases_1:0  |      (10,)      | 3.81469726562e-05 |
   +------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
   ('Total size:', 0.72269439697265625, 'MB')
   ```
3. Then, I initialise the weights of network B as follow:

   ```
   def weight_variable(shape, stddev=0.1, name=""):
       with tf.name_scope(name):
           initial = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=stddev, name=name)
           return tf.Variable(getValueFromNetA(initial.name), name=name)
   ```

   Where the function getValueFromNetA() access the previously created dictionary to return the data. It is defined as:

   ```
   def getValueFromNetA(nameInB):
       # Because networks A and B are very similar, the naming of the tensors is the same.
       # So the first entry in the above table, for NetB the name will be: "NetB/ConvL_1/weights/weights"
       # We just need to change the prefixt to "NetA" and add the "_1" before the ":0"
       nameInA = "NetA" + nameInB[4:] # substitute NetB with NetA
       c_pos = nameInA.index(":")
       nameInA = nameInA[:c_pos] + "_1:0"
       return initDict[str(nameInA)] # returns tensor initialisation data
   ```
4. For the biases I followed the same procedure.

Hope you find this somehow useful. Neater solutions are highly appreciated.